# How to prove that $|\mathbb Z[i]/(2)|=4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove that $|\mathbb Z[i]/(2)|=4$?
I know that $\mathbb Z[i]\simeq\mathbb Z^2$ but I can't get out from here!

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The isomorphism $\Bbb Z[i]\cong\Bbb Z^2$ sends $2\Bbb Z[i]$ to $2\Bbb Z^2=2\Bbb Z\oplus2\Bbb Z$. And $$(A\oplus B)/(C\oplus D)\cong(A/B)\oplus(C/D).$$ It appears you actually do know how to do this problem, since you did it in your previous question...

Comment: Or note that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2)\cong(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x^2+1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulo $2$, every element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is congruent to one of $0$, $1$, $i$, or $1+i$. And they are pairwise incongruent modulo $2$.

Answer (score 1):

As blue mentioned, try the isomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[i] \to \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2 \mathbb{Z}} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2 \mathbb{Z}}$ and then apply the isomorphism theorem. =)